# Why is SSAS required for BizTalk BAM RTA

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-bam

When a BAM activity has RTA enabled my understanding is that the aggregated data is held in a new table of the BAM Primary Import db and updated via triggers from the active and completed activity tables. So why will it not deploy without Analysis Services being present - thus requiring a pricey Enterprise license?

Comment: In my opinion Microsoft pinned the dependency to the BAM aggregations as a whole (both RTA and Scheduled Aggregations) instead of disseminating the different technical aspects of BAM.